# if it possible to get all notifications from all plugins and core?

Tags: wp-admin, notifications

if it possible to get all notifications from all plugins and core?

when notifications appears wordpress insert this to: **`<div id="message" class="some class">notifications  text</div>`**

using `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );`

i want each time that some new notification appears i want to get email with the notification text + all the notifications that the user did not "dismiss".

Thanks

Comment: there are plugins available for this. here's one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/

Comment: Hi @karpstrucking this plugin good for updates only. i speak more on all the notifications using admin_notices

Comment: some help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can find on the link below a full tutorial in how to work with WP notifications.

https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/